# asp.net listview does not hide emptydatatemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am using an asp.net listview control with a custom data  on a page. The list binds to a generic list on page load based on parameters selected on previous pages. This page also has a search button with text boxes at the top to collect any parameters that users may want to search by and when they click search button the list view should rebind and show the data.

In my case in some cases when users clicks the search there is no data matching the user defined search and the empty data template shows up. My empty data template has the exact same headers as the list and a row which has the text "No data returned". But once the empty data template shows up, on a subsequent search which returns back data the empty data template does not hide. The page displays with both the empty data template and the layout template with the records from the search.

My listview has EnableViewstate = false and on search click I collect the parameters user entered in the text boxes and call the method which returns the data(generic list). This list view also has a datapager and on datapagers prerender I am binding the data to the listview. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any code you can post would be helpful, specfically the markup for the listview control.

Comment: If you remove the data pager does it work correctly, minus the pagination of course?

Comment: i just tested and I forgot to mention this before that I have the search boxes ,datapager and listview all in an update panel.I also turned the viewstate=true in an effort to add sorting on the page(and that is working fine).If I remove the update panel this problem does not occur.